# Multiple aggregations on nested structure in a single Spark statement

Tags: apache-spark, aggregation

I have a json structure like this:

```
{
   "a":5,
   "b":10,
   "c":{
      "c1": 3,
      "c4": 5
   }     
}
```

I have a dataframe created  from this structure with several million rows. What I need are aggregation in several keys like this:

```
df.agg(count($"b") as "cntB", sum($"c.c4") as "sumC")
```

Do I just miss the syntax? Or is there a different way to do it? Most important Spark should only scan the data once for all aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but your JSON must be in one line.

Each line = new JSON object.

```
val  json = sc.parallelize(
  "{\"a\":5,\"b\":10,\"c\":{\"c1\": 3,\"c4\": 5}}" :: Nil)
val jsons = sqlContext.read.json(json)

jsons.agg(count($"b") as "cntB", sum($"c.c4") as "sumC").show
```

Works fine - please see that json is formatted to be in one line.

`jsons.printSchema()` is printing:

```
root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c4: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Just found my mistake. The "c" part of the data is sparse and during parsing it was recognized as string due to wrong formatting of input data.